# What's necessary to sucessfully make ajax requests, through jquery, on my server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

```
$.ajax({
    url: imgpath,
    success: function(data) {   
        $(data).find("td > a:contains('.jpg')").each(function() {
            ...
        });
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }
});
```

Im using this to retrieve the name of each .jpg file in a specific folder on my server.

Works like a charm in my WAMP Server, but when it runs from the "real" web server, it just doensn't work.

I was wondering, maybe it is something related with the implemented security policies, but I have no idea where to start looking. I tried enabling the directory listing, but the problem persists.

Is it possible to retrieve like an error log to have an idea of where the problem is?

Comment: You can use Firebug extension for mozilla and use its console to see the errors http://getfirebug.com/logging

Comment: have you looked in the console? alt + cmd + i (mac) (tools > web developer > web console - firefox) whats the location contained in `imgpath` ?

Comment: I use Mozilla's debugger to debug my scripts. There's nothing in the console and no alert showing up. I was not sure what should go in imgpath, im my local server I always used the relative path "/products", but also tried the absolute path "http://example.com/products". None of them worked.